# more elegant xpath solution?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I am scraping a forum and am trying to retrieve stats about the post, specifically the number of views a post gets and the number of replies.

The page source for what I am parsing looks like this:

```
<ul class="ipsDataItem_stats">
<li>
    <span class="ipsDataItem_stats_number">61</span>
    <span class="ipsDataItem_stats_type"> replies</span>
</li>
<li class="ipsType_light">
    <span class="ipsDataItem_stats_number">6,106</span>
    <span class="ipsDataItem_stats_type"> views</span>
</li>
```

And I've hacked together some code that pulls what I'm looking for, but I'm wonder how you xpath experts would have handled this.

```
Stats = node.find_elements_by_xpath('.//ul[@class="ipsDataItem_stats"]')
Replies = (Stats[0].find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ipsDataItem_stats_number"]'))[0].text
Views = (Stats[0].find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ipsDataItem_stats_number"]'))[1].text
```

My solution relies on the stats being in a certain order, and I'm wondering if there's a more accurate way to achieve the same result.

eg psuedo code:

```
Replies = node.find_elements_by_xpath({get span text where class = "ipsDataItem_stats" and sibling span class = "ipsDataItem_stats_type" and text = "replies"})
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `more accurate` or `more elegant` ? What is wrong with these xpath expressions  ?

Comment: What happens when the site renders the page and flips the li elements around so views are first and replies are second?  Or they add an additional stat so Stats[0] needs to become Stats[1] or Stats[2], etc..  I'm looking for a way to more accurately obtain the elements I am after without relying on their position in a list.

Comment: So if you look at my psuedo code, it would be a way to get Replies populated with 1 xpath query, I just don't know how to construct that query.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to more accurately obtain the elements I am
>   after without relying on their position in a list.

The elements can be distinguished from each other by their class names

```
<span class="ipsDataItem_stats_number">61</span>
<span class="ipsDataItem_stats_type"> replies</span>
```

so use the bellow xpath expressions for the first element:

```
.//span[ contains( @class, 'stats_number')]
```

and for the second element

```
.//span[ contains( @class, 'stats_type')]
```

In this way the expressions will resist the change of the element's order.

Comment: There are 2 span elements that contain class = "stats_number".  So wouldn't that just return a list and I'd still need to reference the values based on list order?

Comment: Yes, it gives a list of all matching elements.Just iterate over a list to access individual elements.

Comment: .//span[ contains( @class, 'stats_number')] <-- so for the list returned with the values, as I'm iterating over it, how do I tell which number is replies vs. views?  That information would be in a 2nd list, so I'm back to the original issue of relying on list position.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this with a 2-step pipeline. The first step would be to transform to a cleaner XML format using XSLT, the second would query that clean XML. The cleaned-up XML for this fragment might look like this:

```
<ipsDataItem_stats>
  <replies>61</replies>
  <views>6106</views>
</ipsDataItem_stats>
```

The benefit of this approach is that the clean-up phase is completely reusable and independent of the actual queries you want to run; once written, it makes any subsequent queries very much easier to write.

Comment: Starting to dig through the xslt docs, but most of the examples I've found online are for generating xml using this library.  How does one reformat the output like this using this library?

Comment: Don't try to learn XSLT (or any other language) by looking for examples online. It's a hopelessly inefficient learning strategy. Would you try to learn to drive by looking for video-clips of people driving? Buy yourself a good book and curl up in bed with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at label that describes a stat. The general xpath would look something like this:

```
'//ul[@class="ipsDataItem_stats"][<FILL HERE RECORDS POSITION>]//li[contains(., "<FILL HERE RECORDS LABEL>")]/span[@class="ipsDataItem_stats_number"]'
```

For replies and views we get following xpath:

```
FirstRecordsRepliesXpath = '//ul[@class="ipsDataItem_stats"][0]//li[contains(., "replies")]/span[@class="ipsDataItem_stats_number"]'
FirstRecordsViewsXpath = '//ul[@class="ipsDataItem_stats"][0]//li[contains(., "views")]/span[@class="ipsDataItem_stats_number"]'
```

This way you don't need to know anything about the order. But you need to know labels, which should be ok.